# Adding another Component into angular 2 application

Tags: angular

Here i am trying to create a simple angular application. I have created one more component named tutorialcomponent, than app component. Now using selector of tutorialComponent, i am trying to embed it in app component. But i am not getting output of app component after embedding.
here is my app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TutorialComponent} from './tutorial/tutorial.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `./app.component.html
        <app-tutorial></app-tutorial>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})  
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Angular2 Login App';
}
```

Here is tutorialcomponent,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorial',
  templateUrl: './tutorial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tutorial.component.css']
})
export class TutorialComponent  {


}
```

Here is my output,

[image]

so please suggest me a way to bind components.

Comment: The selector would be `app-tutorial` and templateUrl, not template, would identify the html content.

Comment: <app-tutorial> is selector for for tutorial component. My code for tutorial component is     import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorial',
  templateUrl: './tutorial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tutorial.component.css']
})
export class TutorialComponent  {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `{{title}}<br><app-tutorial></app-tutorial>`,  //this line
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

I think your app component is working as expected. You are not binding the `title` that's wht you are not able to see the message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TutorialComponent } from './tutorial/tutorial.component';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `{{ title }} <br/>
              <app-tutorial></app-tutorial>`,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})  

export class AppComponent {
   public title = 'My Angular2 Login App'; //define as public 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer to have an html file you can try this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Puis dans le fichier html tu remets ceci:

```
<span>{{title}}</span>
<br>
<app-tutorial></app-tutorial>
```

Comment: Thank-you. Its working for my application. Both the components are displaying on browser now.